# JSON_EXTRACT devuelve NULL cuando no debería

Tags: mysql, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON (sin saltos de línea) guardado en la columna `datos` tipo `LONGTEXT`.

`{"clientes": [{"nombreCompleto": "XXXXX", "telefono": "XXXXXX", "email": "XXXXXX"}], "tipoCelebracion": "XXXXXX", "breveDato": "CASA PARTICULAR", "fechaInicioEventoAux": "XXXX", "fechaInicioEvento": "XXXXXX", "idEspacio": 10, "idHorario": 2, "ciudadCat": "XXXXXX", "nAdultos": "XXXXX"}`

¿Por qué devuelve NULL esta consulta?

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(datos, '&.clientes') from eventos where idEvento = 392;
+-----------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(datos, '&.clientes') |
+-----------------------------------+
| NULL                              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: creo recordar que es con $, no con &...

Comment: @Jakala toda la razón. Muchas gracias